# how to get css href link using JS?

Tags: javascript, href

I am using JavaScript for the first time.
Please give me detailed explanation and  test code.

I would like to extract 'javascript: pdfdownload' next to 'onclick' in 'href = # function' under code.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf'); return false;"><span class="on-clickboard">
        <img src="IMG1.png" alt=""></span>NAME
        <span class="icon-right"><img src="IMG.JPG" alt=""></span>
        </a></li>
```

so i use under code that if i catch button_action then give a True to 'value' variale.

```
var button_action = "pdfDonwload"

if(window.loaction.href.indexOf(button_action) != -1){value = 'True'}
```

i don't know thos try is right, and Furthermore, it may be a completely wrong-directional coding.

please help me.

Comment: Could you have another try at explaining your problem? I can't see any connection between what you're asking and the code you've tried.

Comment: I also cannot understand what you are asking, "css href link"? Does this even have anything to do with css? You also have jQuery tag added even though I think jQuery is also not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first must select tag:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // better is use getElementById()
```

then get `getAttribute`

```
var value =  els[0].getAttribute('onclick');
```

now you can set it anywhere.

i suggest you read more...!

Comment: then actual value in 'value' is 'javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf')'?

Comment: value is value of 'onclick' attribute.

Comment: if you need 'javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf')' you can split 'javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf');' return false; to ';' and use it

Comment: @송준석 value.split(';')[0]; // 'javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf')'  [split in js](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: thank you. 
I forgot that the tag I was looking for was not the first.

Answer (score 1):

```
var onclickValue = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('onclick');
    //javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf'); return false;

var firstPart = onclickValue.split(';')[0];
    //javascript:pdfDownload('NAME.pdf')
```